# How to remove all occurrences of any given character from string?

Tags: javascript, regex, string

My code:

```
    function removeFromString(mystring,char){

    let regex = new RegExp(char, 'g');
    let string;
    for(let i; i< mystring.length; i++){
        string = mystring.replace(regex, ''));

    }
    console.log(mystring);
}
removeFromString('Hello How are you','o');
```

This doesn't work. 
Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method [`String.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) doesn't change the string, it creates a new string. Return the result of the replace.

In addition, since you've used the `g` flag in the regex, it will replace all occurrences in the string, so you don't need the for loop.

```js
function removeFromString(mystring, char) {
  const regex = new RegExp(char, 'g');
  return mystring.replace(regex, '');
}
console.log(removeFromString('Hello How are you', 'o'));
```

You can also achieve the same thing with a loop, by rebuilding the string from all characters in the original string the are not the `char`:

```js
function removeFromString(mystring, char) {
  let string = '';
  
  for (let i = 0; i < mystring.length; i++) {
    if(mystring[i] !== char) string += mystring[i];
  }
  
  return string;
}
console.log(removeFromString('Hello How are you', 'o'));
```

Comment: Please note that `char` should be treated carefully as it may include regex metacharacters.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `replace` for it. No need for loop. like

```js
var str = "How are you?";

console.log(str.replace(/o/g, ""))
```

`g` flag is to replace all occurrences

Or Just for fun.

```js
var str = "How are you?";
console.log(str.split("o").join(''))
```

`split` string by your desired character. This will give you an array. Now you can join this array with `''`